# Avoid error quote is expected for attribute parsing Xml

Tags: java, xml

The is a way to avoid this error?

i use this for parsing:

```
try {
            doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new URL(url).openStream());
        } catch (SAXException | IOException | ParserConfigurationException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But i have the error:

```
[Fatal Error] :3:19: Open quote is expected for attribute "attr" associated with an  element type  "elem".
```

Comment: Looks to me like you'll need to go through the value of your url variable

Comment: well, you could always debug your code, and check the value in your debug editor

Comment: i have no control on this XML..i try to avoid the quote control when i parse

Comment: I'm not talking about the xml. I'm talking about your url variable.

Comment: ok but i'm not understand how i can do to fix